# How to speed up the image loading-Facebook api-iphone?

Tags: iphone, facebook-fql, image-loading

Here I am creating an iPhone app using facebook api. I have loaded the friends list and their profile pictures into a table view. But now its running slowly. I want to speed up the loading of the pictures, how can I do that?

Here is my sample code:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result { 
    NSArray* users = result; 
    for (int ndx = 0; ndx < [users count] ; ndx++)
    {
        NSDictionary* user = [users objectAtIndex:ndx]; 
        NSString* name = [user objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *imageName = [user objectForKey:@"pic_big"];
        [imageArray addObject:imageName];
        [friendsList addObject:name];
    }
}
```

In tableview delegate method:

```
imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

        cell.imageView.image =image;
```

And also the picture sizes are different. 
Please help
thanks

Comment: Please show some of ur coding...

Comment: i have added the code, please go through it. thanks.

Comment: U are tryin to do the image loading  synchronously.....Please try to do it using async URL request. That might help...

Comment: download a smaller image

Comment: how can i do that? I have no idea how to that...please help.

Comment: I have found some asynchronous methods, but i'm looking for a simple code, i have an array that contains all the image links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the Lazyloading concept you can make it run fastly.
Just download [this](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/downloads) class for lazyloading.

It is very easy to impelement.

```
 #import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"  // Import this

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     ------------------ 
     ------------------
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, should i import all the class files into my app?

Comment: have one problem here, when it load at first time all image sizes are same. Then if scroll down, its fine. But when i scroll back to the top, the picture sizes are varying.

Comment: i am getting these images from facebook api, first time it is ok, the problem occurs when i scroll back only. why so?

Comment: I too got the same problem first at that time I am using the large resolution images. After I changed that to smaller resolution images it is now working nicely..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4416/discussion-between-trisha-and-john)